# Translation of "modulo"

Tags: traduction, demande-de-mot

What is a French translation for the word [modulo](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/modulo) in the meaning

> Correcting or adjusting for something, as by leaving something out of account.

An example sentence (from the same link) is

> This proposal is the best so far, **modulo** the fact that parts of it need modification.

I looked up in a dictionary but it cannot find this word. Would it be *si on ne prend pas en compte*?

> Cette proposition est la meilleure jusqu'ici, **si on ne prend pas en compte** le fait que certaines parties en ont besoin de modification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends. If the audience knows some maths or computer science, "modulo" would be readily understood, IMHO. Otherwise,

> Cette proposition est la meilleure jusqu'ici, si on ne prend pas en compte le fait que certaines parties ont besoin de modification.

is perfectly correct (without "en"). More relaxed:

> Cette proposition est la meilleure jusqu'ici, sauf pour certaines parties qui ont besoin de modifications.

This one also might work:

> Cette proposition est la meilleure jusqu'ici, modulo quelques modifications.

One more:

> Cette proposition est la meilleure jusqu'ici, avec juste quelques modifications.

But maybe the meaning is starting to drift: does the original want to stress that if we took modifications into account, it would no longer be the best proposal, or that it is the best, but will require a bit of work?

Answer (score 3):

A better translation of **modulo** in this case would be **[à ceci près](http://www.linguee.fr/francais-anglais/traduction/%C3%A0+ceci+pr%C3%A8s+que.html)** or even **[à cela près](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C3%A0_cela_pr%C3%A8s)**:

> Cette proposition est la meilleure, **à ceci près** qu'on ne prend pas en compte le fait que certaines parties ont besoin de modification.